# Drawing rectangle can not shadow my image

Tags: konvajs

I am trying to drawing something over an existing image object using Konvajs.
so I code like this:

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'underground-map-container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: 1121.6
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
    var parking_img = new Konva.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        width: 1328,
        height: 878.6
    });
    layer.add(parking_img);
    stage.add(layer);
};
imageObj.src = "../static/img/underground-map.png";


var rect = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 700,
    y: 50,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: 'blue',
    opacity:1
});
layer.add(rect);

var rect1 = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 800,
    y: 50,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: 'red',
    opacity:1
});
layer.add(rect1);
```

rect1 can shadow rect, however, both of them can not shadow my image. Does anyone know how to do that, thank you!

[image: following is the actual output]

Comment: Do you want just show shapes on top of the image?

Comment: Exactly. but my background image always shows on top, even if I set the Zindex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is added to a layer when it is loaded. It happens AFTER rectangles are added, so the image is placed on top. To move the image you can use:

1. `parking_img.moveToBottom()`
2. or `parking_img.setZIndex(0)`

**Important:** Use those methods only after you added the image to a layer like:

```
var parking_img = new Konva.Image({
    image: imageObj,
    width: 1328,
    height: 878.6
});
layer.add(parking_img);
parking_img.moveToBottom();
layer.draw();
```

Comment: This works for me. I need to figure out the order that things happen. (when is the image loaded, when rect is added )Thank you.